# Swift IOS Не фокусируется на UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development

Такая проблема что я в коде добавляю в StackView (Vertical) свою View под названием ProfileContactField (ProfileContactField состоит из двух UITextField и одного Label). Так вот при добавлении в StackView с помощью метода addArrangedSubview (пробовал даже просто addSubView) и при попытки написать что то в ProfileContactField не фокусируется вообще на UITextField. UserInteraction везде проверил. Проверял сами UITextField. При это если добавить в StackView обычный UITextField то все работает. Так же пробовал ProfileContactField добавить в главную View (self.view.addSubview) в это случае все работает. Я новенький в разработки под IOS из-за этого опыта имею мало. Пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Тестовый проект можете куда то залить для воспроизведения?

Comment: Насколько понял, у вас не появляется клавиатура? Если так, то, возможно, stackView как-то перебивает `isEditable` или `isUserInteractionEnable`. Не уверен, но попробуйте проверить